# MaterialPageRoute not opening new screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a new screen when a PopupMenuItem is tapped. I am using showMenu() to create the popup menu.

The code calling the new screen looks like this:-

```
items: [
    PopupMenuItem(
      onTap: () {
        print(movie.title);
        // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        //     builder: (context) => MoreInfo(movie: movie)));
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => MoreInfo(movie: movie)));
      },
      child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => MoreInfo(movie: movie)));
          },
          child: Text("More info")),
```

and MoreInfo screen code looks like this:-

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
    ),
    title: Text(widget.movie.title),
  ),
```

However, using the onTap field of PopupMenuItem does not open a new screen. It is printing out movie.title though. I also have the text of the menu item wrapped with an InkWell, when I do click on the text, a new screen does show up, but there is no content on it. Just an empty screen with Colors.indigo background color as specified in MoreInfo, but with none of the other elements such as AppBar.
What could be going wrong here? Do I need to use another type of Navigation?

Comment: remove the InkWell from the PopupMenuItem. You already got onTap !! Just place the Text  as child to the PopupMenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code works as well:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {


const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                showMenu(
                    context: context,
                    position: const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    items: [
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => MoreInfo()));
                        },
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => MoreInfo()));
                            },
                            child: const Text("More info")),
                      )
                    ]);
              },
              child: const Text('push me'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MoreInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  MoreInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MoreInfo> createState() => _MoreInfoState();
}

class _MoreInfoState extends State<MoreInfo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
        ),
        title: const Text('widget.movie.title'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('hi'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```